# Adding p value significance stars (*) to ggplot dot-and-whisker

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot, would anyone know how to add significance stars (*) to a dot-and-whisker plot using *P* values taken from a dataframe?

Ideally I would like to have '*' for <0.05 and '**' for <0.01

example code below

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(dotwhisker)

m1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl + disp + gear, data = mtcars)
m2 <- update(m1, . ~ . + hp)

m1 = tidy(m1)
m1$model = "model 1"
m2 = tidy(m2)
m2$model = "model 2"

m4 = rbind(m1,m2)

small_multiple(m4, dot_args = list(aes(shape = term, col = term)),
                       whisker_args = list(aes(linetype = term))
  ) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) + ylab("") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,
             colour = "grey60",
             linetype = 2) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)
  )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before rendering the plot, you could mutate a column for asterisks.

```
m4 <- m4 |> 
  filter(term != "(Intercept)") |> 
  mutate(pval_star = case_when(p.value < 0.01 ~ "**",
                               p.value < 0.05 ~ "*",
                               .default = ""))
```

And rendering plot with `geom_text()`.

```r
small_multiple(m4, dot_args = list(aes(shape = term, col = term)),
               whisker_args = list(aes(linetype = term))
) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) + 
  ylab("")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,
             colour = "grey60",
             linetype = 2) +
  geom_text(data=m4, 
            aes(label=pval_star, y= estimate + 2*std.error),
            size=10) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>